# What is the vertical spacing between the first line and the top of the document

Tags: spacing, margins, memoir, fontsize

I have set margins zero and no indent for a document (memoir). I’m trying to figure out what the spacing between the top of the page and the first line is and how to change it.

I’ve discovered a couple of things. It depends on the font size. It is not baselineskip. For Huge it is almost equal to some capital letters. It is not consistent with baselineskip over font sizes. It changes from 0.8 (10.88 pt) of baselineskip (13.6 pt) for the default font size to around 0.56 (16.8 pt) of baselineskip (30 pt) for Huge.

Comment: Could it be `\topskip`??

Comment: If you increase font sizes, the distance from the top of the document to the 1st baseline will be the larger of these two lengths: `\setbox0=\hbox{X}\the\ht0,\the\topskip`, where the `X` is set in the current font size.  Typically, the 1st dimension overtakes the 2nd (which is fixed) around `\Large` size.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes indeed it is topskip. Except when the line height exceeds it, then it become the line height.

Comment: In my prior comment, I assumed the use of capital letters in the 1st line.  But you are more correct...it is the actual line height, which can be smaller, if no caps appear in the 1st line.